# Loading data to TextView in Android

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a XML tag like "Yes,No,Dontknow " and I am parsing the XML file and getting the data. Now I need to display each option in separate TextView, i.e: 'yes' should be displayed in one TextView, 'No' should be displayed in another TextView, and 'Dontknow' should be displayed in another TextView, but how can I do this, can anyone give me some idea (I am new to Android).

Comment: cnt understnd by mean of ur xml tag can u put ur xml file whch u r parsing?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862451/loading-data-to-text-view-in-android

Comment: can you pls paste code whr you getting tht string from parsing

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862451/loading-data-to-text-view-in-android) **and** [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863103/loading-data-which-are-seperated-by-comma-to-seperate-textviews-in-android), all by the same user

Comment: Third identical question from the same poster. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863103/loading-data-which-are-seperated-by-comma-to-seperate-textviews-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862451/loading-data-to-text-view-in-android You've been given a perfectly good answer by Christian - accept it, use it and please stop posting.

Comment: I've merged all dupes.  Sowmya, please stop asking the same question over and over again.  You're making android devs look bad.  You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4862451/edit) this question to add detail, or leave comments on answers if something needs to be straightened out.

Comment: @ Vladimir Ivanov ,,am displaying to a single textview like following code  String strBufferResponse="";
  for (int intLstLength=0;intLstLength<objDataSet.getQuestion().size();intLstLength++)
  {
   strBufferResponse=strBufferResponse+objDataSet.getQuestion().get(intLstLength).toString();
  }
  tvResponse.setText(strBufferResponse);

Answer (score 2):

Use [setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) method of TextView to load text into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string tokenizer:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(theString, ",");
while( tokens.hasMoreTokens() ){
    String token = tokens.nextToken();
    // here you must have the reference to the text view...
    textView.setText(token);
}
```

If you are creating the text views programmatically, then you must create or reference those text views inside the loop. Other wise, if the text views are static, you better put each token inside an array or something (words[0] will be Yes, word[1] will be No, etc) and then you set those strings manually.

Answer (score 1):

parse xml file store that in a string.take an array like  String[] array = parsedstring.split(","); then take 3 text views ,put array[0],array[1],array[2] on to textview

Answer (score 1):

You can just declare 3 separate `TextView` in you `Activity` layout file. Using attribute `android:text` you can assign the text for the `TextView`.

Example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yes"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split comma-separated strings, take a look at using `java.util.StringTokenizer`. You can tell it to use `,` as the token separator.