# loading data which are seperated by comma(,) to seperate textviews in android

Tags: android, xml, textview

hii every buddy,

am displaying parsed xml contents to a textview here i faced a problem, i have a tag like Yes,No,DontKnow  in  xml file,i can able to parse the data & display it in a textview, but i need to display each data which are seperated by comma(,) to seperate textviews   like 'yes' should be displayed in a text view & 'No' should be displayed in other textview,& 'dontknow' should be displayed in another textview, how to do that, can any buddy give some idea ,,,,,,thanx in advance(I am new to android)